# Drupal 7 When a new user registers, where is the confirmation e-mail sent?

Tags: emails, users

Im using Drupal 7, when a new user registers an account I want to be able to approve/deny their membership and then allow them on the website as a registered user. When a new user registers, where is that registration e-mail sent to? And can I change where that e-mail goes?

Comment: It should be whatever you set as the "site" email address at admin » config » site information. Emails only get sent when you have configured new users to require admin approval.

Answer (score 4):

Set the new user account setting to "administrator approval is required" here:

Admin > Configuration > People > Account Settings

[image]